# Windows couldnot search for new updates

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-server-2012-r2

While applying the March OS patches , I am getting the below issue :

OS - Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

I have tried to check on below fixes .

1. netsh winsock reset and Rebooted OS , doesn't work .
2. Solving the Windows Update 80072EE2 Error

In the registry editor, browse to the folder in the left hand panel to the

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate
```

delete the keys in the right hand pane called `WUServer and WIStatusServer` .

**NOTE :** First of all , the windowsupdate folder doesnot exist in machine . This doesn't help .

Nothing helped so far . Can anyone help me .

Please find the error log :

**Key points:**

```
[AGENT_DETECTION_FAILED]    
80072ee2    
AutomaticUpdatesWuApp   
Failure Software Synchronization    
Windows Update Client failed to detect with error 0x80072ee2.
```

SLS Making request with URL {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77}/x64/6.3.9600.0/0?CH=839&L=en-US;ja-JP&P=&PT=0x7&WUA=7.9.9600.18838 Misc WARNING: Send failed with hr = 80072ee2. Misc   WARNING: Proxy List used: <(null)> Bypass List used : <(null)> Auth Schemes used :  Misc  WARNING: Send request failed, hr:0x80072ee2 Misc    WARNING: WinHttp: SendRequestUsingProxy failed for >## RESUMED  ## AU: Search for updates [CallId = {9C43E378-AC70-49EB-BFDE-EFC4884478E7} ServiceId = {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77}] AU   # WARNING: Search callback failed, result = 0x80072EE2 AU ######### AU    ##  END  ##  AU: Search for updates  [CallId = {9C43E378-AC70-49EB-BFDE-EFC4884478E7} ServiceId = {9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77}] AU    ############# AU    All AU searches complete. AU      # WARNING: Failed to find updates with error code 80072ee2

Comment: 0x80072EE2 = ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT does normal internet work?

Comment: @magicandre1981 , no our servers do not have internet enabled . Other hand patches will be pushed to the servers manually .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below troubleshooting helped me to fix the issue:

1. Open run --> Type Gpedit.msc
2. Computer configuration --> Administrative templates
3. Windows Components --> Windows Update

Compare the below three settings under Windows update with the server where the Windows Patching update is properly working:

1. Always automatically restart at the scheduled time
2. Configure Automatic updates
3. Specify intranet Microsoft update service location

The above three settings are disabled in my case . I did compare the settings with the working patching update process server and all went good .

Hope this helps someone . Good Day